# string to JSON parse , javascript runtime invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read the values of properties in this  string, when i try to parse it , i get invalid character. Can you tell me whats wrong here

data = [{'title' : 'location 1','lat' : '29.769730','lng' : '-95.257181','desc' : 'Apartments',},{'title' : 'location 2','lat' : '29.852264','lng' : '-95.469999','desc' : 'location description',},];

var test = $.parseJSON(data)l

error - Unhandled exception at line 138, column 13 in http://localhost:17765/Loc/index
0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Comment: Why do you think `data` is a string?

Comment: Becouse you use ' and not " that not a valid JSON format.

Comment: It is  being returned from an mvc5 controller method as a string

Comment: Would you please edit the question to reflect the real data.

Comment: Its the real data, I just changed the values of title and desc to dummy values.

Comment: You say in the comment above, that you're getting data as a string, however, `data` in the question is not a string, it's an array. Also, if your server responses with such a string when requesting JSON, there's something really off on your server ...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `data` is not a string. It is an array. It does not need parsing (other than by the JavaScript compiler). Just discard `$.parseJSON` and work with the data.

```js
data = [{'title' : 'location 1','lat' : '29.769730','lng' : '-95.257181','desc' : 'Apartments',},{'title' : 'location 2','lat' : '29.852264','lng' : '-95.469999','desc' : 'location description',},];

data.forEach(o => console.log(o.title));
```

---

> It is being returned from an mvc5 controller method as a string

If your code does not accurately reflect the data you have and you do have a string, then it would need parsing.

The code you provided is, however, not valid JSON which:

- Requires strings be quoted with `"` not `'`
- Does not allow trailing `,` after the last item in an array.

You need to fix the server side code so it returns real JSON.

This will probably involve replacing some code which attempts to generate JSON by mashing together strings with some which uses a JSON aware library function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222559/how-to-return-json-with-mvc-controller)).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, try this:

```
var data = '[{"title" : "location 1","lat" : "29.769730","lng" : "-95.257181","desc" : "Apartments"},{"title" : "location 2","lat" : "29.852264","lng" : "-95.469999","desc" : "location description"}]';

var test = $.parseJSON(data);
```

validate your JSON [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
[{"title" : "location 1","lat" : "29.769730","lng" : "-95.257181","desc" : "Apartments"},{"title" : "location 2","lat" : "29.852264","lng" : "-95.469999","desc" : "location description"}]
```